# Перечисления в книге (пример)

Tags: java

Не очень понял, как так можно писать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь в идее я набрал этот код, но компилятор ругается, как сделать этот код рабочим?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он не ругается, а предупреждает, что переменная не инициализирована

Comment: @AlexanderChernin но в книге же не инициализирована?

Comment: `Пропускаем несколько десятков строк` - вот там предполагается скорее всего что она инициализируется. Переменные не обязательно всегда инициализировать во время объявления, можно и где-то позже. Главное чтобы во время использования она уже была гарантировано проинициализировано.

Comment: @iksuy спасибо большое, а можете написать этот код в единой конструкции? Чтобы был рабочий пример и отправьте в ответы, я приму. Потому что книга популярная и много кому поможет в будущем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компилятор ругается по-другому. Волнистыми линиями подчеркивает IDE. Желательно чтобы автор показал текст ошибки.

А так можно предположить, что автор тупо переписывает текст из книжи в редактор, и естественно получает неправильный исходный код java.

В java-файле должно быть определение класса. А получается определение класса и ещё что-то совершенно недопустимое.

Очевидно автор книжки предполагал, что это все будет внутри какого-то класса, который он, как обычно, опустил. Что-то вроде этого:

```
public class MyClass {
    public enum Members { JERRY, BOBBY, PHIL };
    public Members selectedMember;

    // всё остальное

}
```

Другой путь - это два исходных файла. Один `Members.java` с определением перечисления:

```
public enum Members { 
    JERRY, 
    BOBBY, 
    PHIL 
}
```

Другой `MyClass.java`:

```
public class MyClass {
    public Members selectedMember;

    // всё оствльное
}
```